# Nested dictionary strange behavior

Tags: swift

I want to make a map of figures

Code :

```
class figures {
    var maps : [NSDictionary]
    init() {
        self.maps = [
            [
                "map" : [
                    [ "x" : -0.5, "y" : -0.5]
                ],
                "color" : UIColor.redColor()
            ],
            [
                "map" : [
                    [ "x" : 0, "y" : 0],  [ "x" : 0, "y" : -1],  [ "x" : -1, "y" : 0],  [ "x" : -1, "y" : -1]
                ],
                "color" : UIColor.blueColor()
            ],
            [
                "map" : [
                    [ "x" : 0, "y" : -0.5], [ "x" : -1, "y" : -0.5]
                ],
                "color" : UIColor.yellowColor()
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

this code is valid, but i want to add 1 more figure in this dictionary, like:

```
        [
            "map" : [
                [ "x" : -1, "y" : -0.5], [ "x" : 0.5, "y" : -0.5], [ "x" : -0.5, "y" : -0.5]
            ],
            "color" : UIColor.cyanColor()
        ]
```

and now i got the following error:

```
Could not find an overload for '-' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

but if replace -0.5 for x in last dict with 0.5 it's valid again

```
 [
            "map" : [
                [ "x" : -1, "y" : -0.5], [ "x" : 0.5, "y" : -0.5], [ "x" : 0.5, "y" : -0.5]
            ],
            "color" : UIColor.cyanColor()
        ]
```

What's happening? Anybody help

Comment: Please show the code that gives you an error as the figure you describe could be inserted into many places.

Comment: The error is on the self.map declaration

Comment: Show all literal you assign to `self.maps`.

Comment: Dumb question: You didn't miss the separating comma right before your new map element?

Answer (score 0):

The swift compiler has known issues with large statements like this one. Better build your array step-by-step:

```
self.maps.append([
    "map" : [
                [ "x" : -0.5, "y" : -0.5]
            ],
            "color" : UIColor.redColor()
])

self.maps.append([
    "map" : [
                [ "x" : 0, "y" : 0],  [ "x" : 0, "y" : -1],  [ "x" : -1, "y" : 0],  [ "x" : -1, "y" : -1]
            ],
            "color" : UIColor.blueColor()
])

...
```

Comment: This didn't help. Even if i make     
var q = ["map" : [
            [ "x" : -1, "y" : -0.5],
            [ "x" : 0.5, "y" : -0.5],
            [ "x" : -0.5, "y" : -0.5]
            ], "color" : UIColor.cyanColor() ]
        
    } 
Thats throw the same error